# nodes in p:treeTable still selectable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to make some rows of a `<p:treeTable>` unselectable. I noticed that there is the `setSelectable(boolean)` method in the `TreeNode` class. When I set it to false, the row remains selectable. I'm using `PrimeFaces` version 10.0.7. How can I solve it?

My <p:treeTable> is:

```
<p:treeTable value="#{bean.root}" var="r" rowKey="#{r.id}" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{bean.selectedNode}">
    <p:column headerText="#{text['name']}" sortBy="#{r.name}" filterBy="#{r.name}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{r.name}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:treeTable>
```

In my bean, variables are defined as:

```
private TreeNode root;
private TreeNode selectedNode;
```

and I use these two functions to initialize the tree:

```
private TreeNode getNode(String folder, List<String> path, TreeNode root) {
    TreeNode node = root.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(c -> folder.compareTo((String) ((Map) c.getData()).get("name")) == 0).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (node == null) {
        Map f = new HashMap<>();
        f.put("name", folder);
        node = new DefaultTreeNode(f, root);
        node.setSelectable(false);
    }
    node = !path.isEmpty() ? getNode(path.get(0), path.subList(1, path.size()), node) : node;
    return node;
}

private TreeNode initRoot(List<Map> els) {
    TreeNode retVal = new DefaultTreeNode(new HashMap<>(), null);
    els.stream().forEach(el -> {
        String groupingPath = (String) el.get("groupingPath");
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(groupingPath)) {
            List<String> folders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(groupingPath.split("/")));
            TreeNode node = getNode(folders.get(0), folders.subList(1, folders.size()), retVal);
            new DefaultTreeNode(el, node);
        } else {
            new DefaultTreeNode(el, retVal);
        }
    });
    return retVal;
}

protected void init() {
    List<Map> els = new ArrayList();
    // populate els
    ...
    root = initRoot(els);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]